# Encontrar horário dentro de um range de horas

Tags: c#

Estou tentando desenvolver uma lógica onde existirá um horário qualquer que eu preciso encontrar dentro de um range de horas (Hora inicial e hora final)

Porém não consigo fazer a comparação corretamete e/ou não estou tratando certo.

Nos testes usei a hora de comparação: **03:37:33** para encontrar nos ranges

Segue código:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        DateTime dtImportacao = new DateTime(2019,07,01,03,33,37);

        TimeSpan[] datasInicias = new TimeSpan[]
        {

        new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(00,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(23,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(19,00,01),
        new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(23,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(08,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(19,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(19,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(22,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(23,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(06,00,01)
    };
        TimeSpan[] datasFinais = new TimeSpan[]
        {
        new TimeSpan(23,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(23,59,59),
        new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(19,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(05,59,59),
        new TimeSpan(23,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(20,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(05,45,59),
        new TimeSpan(22,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(06,00,00),
        new TimeSpan(22,59,59)
        };



        for (int i = 0; i < datasInicias.Length; i++)
        {


            if (TimeSpan.Compare(dtImportacao.TimeOfDay, datasInicias[i]) == -1 || TimeSpan.Compare(dtImportacao.TimeOfDay, datasFinais[i]) == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Parametro de Comparação: {0}   | {1}  Até {2} Fora", dtImportacao.TimeOfDay, datasInicias[i], datasFinais[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Parametro de Comparação: {0}   | {1}  Até {2} Dentro", dtImportacao.TimeOfDay, datasInicias[i], datasFinais[i]);
            }


        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Retorno do console:

```
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 06:00:00  Até 23:00:00 Fora
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 00:00:00  Até 23:59:59 Dentro
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 23:00:00  Até 06:00:00 Fora
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 06:00:00  Até 19:00:00 Fora
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 19:00:01  Até 05:59:59 Fora
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 06:00:00  Até 23:00:00 Fora
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 23:00:00  Até 06:00:00 Fora
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 08:00:00  Até 20:00:00 Fora
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 19:00:00  Até 06:00:00 Fora
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 19:00:00  Até 05:45:59 Fora
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 06:00:00  Até 22:00:00 Fora
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 22:00:00  Até 06:00:00 Fora
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 23:00:00  Até 06:00:00 Fora
//Parametro de Comparação: 03:33:37 | 06:00:01  Até 22:59:59 Fora
```

Como deveria sair:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque está a comparar `TimeSpan` com `DateTime`?

Comment: TimeSpan são intervalos de tempo, não são datas como você indica nas suas variáveis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A expressão está verificando se o horário está dentro do período específico, mas você não está contando se o período for outro dia, portanto, se passar das 24hrs, o resultado não estará dentro do campo do dia anterior.

A expressão que você precisa é:

```
bool dentroDoPeriodo = !(min <= max ? (val >= min && val <= max) : (val >= min || val <= max));
```

Explicação da expressão:

```
var min = datasInicias[i];
var max = datasFinais[i];
var val = dtImportacao;

bool dentroDoPeriodo =
! (                       // Inverte o resultado lógico da expressão
    min <= max            // Se o horário inicial for < que o final       [1]
    ?                     // Início da condição em-linha
    (                     // (Condição Verdadeira de [1]) Se [1] == True
        val >= min        // Se o horário de importação for maior ou igual ao inicial
        &&                // E também se
        val <= max        // o mesmo for menor ou igual ao horário final
    ) : (                 // (Condição Falsa de [1]) Se [1] == False
        val >= min        // Se o horário de importação for maior ou igual ao inicial
        ||                // Ou também se
        val <= max        // o mesmo for menor ou igual ao horário final
    )                     // Retorna o sub-circuíto de [1].
);                        // Retorna o circuíto [1]
```

> Além disso, a comparação de `DateTime` e `TimeSpan` não faz sentido nesta situação. Você está comparando **horas com horas**, não **datas com horas**. Mude no seu código:
>
> de `DateTime dtImportacao = new DateTime(2019,07,01,03,33,37);`
>
> para: `TimeSpan dtImportacao = new TimeSpan(03, 37, 33);`

---

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NGVMU8).

Comment: Estou adaptando seu código para javascript, muito bom.

Answer (score 1):

Você não está considerando que as horas possam atravessar o dia.

Basicamente, o que você precisa é alterar a validação para algo como:

```
Inicio > Fim
 ? data <= Inicio && data <= Fim
 : data >= Inicio && data <= Fim
```

O que pode ser simplificado para:

```
(Inicio > Fim && data <= Inicio || data >= Inicio) && data <= Fim;
```

Veja o código completo. Tentar dar uma melhorada na estrutura do código pra ficar mais legível.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

struct Intervalo
{
    public Intervalo(TimeSpan inicio, TimeSpan fim) 
    {
        Inicio = inicio;
        Fim = fim;
    }

    public TimeSpan Inicio { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Fim { get; set; }
    public bool AtravessaDia => Inicio > Fim;

    public bool EstáNoIntervalo(TimeSpan data)
    {
        return AtravessaDia 
            ? data <= Inicio && data <= Fim
            : data >= Inicio && data <= Fim;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime dtImportacao = new DateTime(2019, 07, 01, 03, 33, 37);

        var intervalos = new []
        {
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(23, 59, 00)),
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(23, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(02, 00, 00)),
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(00, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59)),          
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(23, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00)),
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(19, 00, 00)),          
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(19, 00, 01), new TimeSpan(05, 59, 59)),          
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(23, 00, 00)),
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(23, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00)),
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(08, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(20, 00, 00)),
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(19, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00)),
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(19, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00)),
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(02, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(04, 00, 00)),          
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(02, 59, 00), new TimeSpan(03, 00, 00)),      
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(03, 34, 00), new TimeSpan(03, 40, 00)),      
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(03, 32, 00), new TimeSpan(03, 40, 00)),   
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(03, 40, 00), new TimeSpan(03, 34, 00)),   
            new Intervalo(new TimeSpan(03, 40, 00), new TimeSpan(03, 32, 00)),               
        };

        WriteLine($"Parâmetro de Comparação: {dtImportacao.TimeOfDay}\n");
        foreach(var intervalo in intervalos)
            WriteLine($"{intervalo.Inicio} - {intervalo.Fim} = {(intervalo.EstáNoIntervalo(dtImportacao.TimeOfDay) ? "Dentro" : "Fora")} ");      
    }
}
```

<sup>**[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/ptso395050)**</sup>

Comment: Não sabia que você era o @jfbueno até ver este link.

Comment: @CypherPotato Como assim? Não sabia que eu era o jfbueno da onde?

Comment: Já tinha visto esse nick em algum lugar, provavelmente aqui, *repl.it/@jfbueno*